# unable to execute .Net core runtime commands

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-runtime

Whenever i run dotnet command say for example `dotnet --list-runtime` it gives me below error
`A fatal error occurred. The folder [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr] does not exist`
Please note .net runtime is already installed on my machine

Comment: If that folder doesn't exist, the runtime is apparently not properly installed. Try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add dotnet to system path.

1. Start the System Control Panel applet (Start - Settings - Control Panel -  System).
2. Select the Advanced tab.
3. Click the Environment Variables button.
4. Under System Variables, select Path, then click Edit.
5. Add C:\Program Files\dotnet to path.
6. Save and close all CMD windows.
   Should work now.

Give that a go.